# jQuery search string in string in comb. with AJAX

Tags: jquery, string, find, contains

Hello again stackoverflow!

So i have this file, called `servercheck.php`. I want to use ajax to load the contents. If the contents contains an `1`, i want to return true, else, return false.

So i already have this:

```
$.get('servercheck.php', function(data) {
    // Now i wanna search the string data for an 1
});
```

I already searched through `:contains` and `.find()` but that is both for HTML tags...

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `data` might look like? What's the data type - just plain text, or something more structured, like JSON or XML?

Comment: Its just like `1` ... with some spaces around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use javascript indexOf:

```
$.get('servercheck.php', function(data) {
    if(data.indexOf("1") != -1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery deferred objects can help you here.  The best place to start will be here

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to send the data to search for firstly then the coming data is the result of search and specify the data format for returned data from server i use json

```
$.get("servercheck.php",{key:'data-to-search-for'},function(data){
alert(data.count);
alert(data.results[1]);
},'json');
```

this is depending on how you render the json with php count , array of result add variables as you can

i always use post instead of get!!! don't know why but i prefer it